# Create column with dplyr based on value and also frequency of another column, in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I will edit the post name shortly as I think up a better title, but for the time being, a short example below highlights what I am struggling with:

```
dput(mydf)
structure(list(gameID = c("34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "25", 
"25", "25")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

mydf
    gameID
1     34
2     34
3     34
4     34
5     34
6     25
7     25
8     25
```

(garbocCol is included only so that the dataframe had >1 column - otherwise please ignore.) This feels like it should be a fairly straightforward data manipulation problem. I would like to create a new column that is simply the gameID column pasted with the count of that gameID. I am thus seeking the following output:

```
mydf
  gameID    newCol
1     34     34-1
2     34     34-2
3     34     34-3
4     34     34-4
5     34     34-5
6     25     25-1
7     25     25-2
8     25     25-3
```

The gameID column is already a character, and the newCol is preferably going to be type character as well. I am working within a long-ish dplyr chain, and am trying to get the following to work:

```
mydf <- mydf %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(newCol = paste0(gameID, '-', {what goes here}))
```

I am fairly easily able to do this with a for-loop, however a dplyr solution would be much better.

Comment: i should remove garbocol it is making the post more confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to `paste` with sequence, get the sequence with `row_number()` grouped by 'gameID' and `paste` to create the 'newCol'

```
mydf %>%
    group_by(gameID) %>%
    mutate(newCol = paste(gameID, row_number(), sep = '-'))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   gameID [2]
#  gameID garboCol newCol
#  <fct>     <dbl> <chr> 
#1 34            1 34-1  
#2 34            2 34-2  
#3 34            3 34-3  
#4 34            4 34-4  
#5 34            5 34-5  
#6 25            6 25-1  
#7 25            7 25-2  
#8 25            8 25-3
```

---

If we want to make this shorter, an option is `rowid` from `data.table`.  Advantage is that it won't create the group attributes in the output

```
library(data.table)
mydf %>% 
  mutate(newCol = paste(gameID, rowid(gameID), sep='-'))
#   gameID garboCol newCol
#1     34        1   34-1
#2     34        2   34-2
#3     34        3   34-3
#4     34        4   34-4
#5     34        5   34-5
#6     25        6   25-1
#7     25        7   25-2
#8     25        8   25-3
```

Or use it with `glue` (from `glue`)

```
library(glue)
mydf %>%
     mutate(newCol = glue("{gameID}-{rowid(gameID)}"))
```

Comment: do you think this could be done without group_by'ing? if not its alright, but the group_by has the unintended consequence of converting to a tibble, which is converting a lot of character classes to ints (even though they should remain character types)

Comment: actually the last comment is a lie - i handle column class types further down in the code, so it's okay

Comment: @Canovice  You can use `rowid` from `data.table`. i.e. `mydf %>% mutate(newCol = paste(gameID, rowid(gameID), sep='-'))`

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you had in mind.

```
mydf %>% 
 group_by(gameID) %>% 
 dplyr::mutate(newCol = paste0(gameID, '-', seq_along(gameID)))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   gameID [2]
#  gameID garboCol newCol
#  <fct>     <dbl> <chr> 
#1 34            1 34-1  
#2 34            2 34-2  
#3 34            3 34-3  
#4 34            4 34-4  
#5 34            5 34-5  
#6 25            6 25-1  
#7 25            7 25-2  
#8 25            8 25-3
```